# Как быстро писать фронтенд на java?

Tags: frontend, web-apps, java, intellij-idea

И вот ещё какой вопрос:
Как быстро в Intellij IDEA разрабатывать фронтэнд для java-ee веб-приложений? А то сейчас получается я правлю одну строчку в css, жму Redeploy, среда мне заново пересобирает проект, собирает .war файл и деплоит его на локальный Tomcat. Итого около 30 секунд на то, чтобы посмотреть, как будет смотреться новое начертание текста в n-цатой строчке. 
Может быть именно для этого в Thymeleaf предусмотрена возможность корректного отображения страничек вне сервера приложений?

Comment: Именно для этого в Thymeleaf предусмотрена возможность корректного отображения страничек вне сервера приложений.

Comment: @a_gura, спасибо, что подтвердили догадку, этот способ намного быстрее, чем "update resourses" в exploded war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При изменении css не надо делать redeploy всего приложения. Достаточно обновить ресурсы в exploded war. И это будет быстрее.

Comment: во, а я думаю, куда пропал пункт "обновить ресурсы" из списка "что сделать" в IDEA. Нужно деплоить exploded, а не archive.